# How to rewrite this simple unDRY laravel method

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, dry

I'm wondering how can I rewrite the following User model eloquent business logic to be a bit more DRY. I'm passing three parameters to the model, where all of them are optional, to narrow down the DB search. I'm sure there has to be a elegant way to do this, but it is beyond me at the moment.

```
public function guests_age($location_id, $year, $gender)
{
    if($location_id && $year && $gender)
    {
        return Guest::select('age')
            ->where('location_id', '=', $location)
            ->where('created_at', '=', $year)
            ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
            ->get();
    }
    elseif($location_id && $year && !$gender)
    {
        return Guest::select('age')
            ->where('location_id', '=', $location)
            ->where('created_at', '=', $year)
            ->get();
    }
    elseif($location_id && !$year && !$gender)
    {
        return Guest::select('age')
            ->where('location_id', '=', $location)
            ->get();
    }
   ... and so on to cover all cases...

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method

```
public function guests_age($location_id, $year, $gender)
{

    $this->qry = Guest::select('age');

    if($location_id)
    {
        $this->qry->where('location_id', '=', $location);

    }
    if($year)
    {
        $this->qry->->where('created_at', '=', $year)

    }
    if($gender)
    {

        $this->qry->where('gender', '=', $gender)

    }

    return $this->qry->get()
   ... and so on to cover all cases...

}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! This might be a really silly question, but how do I get access to this function (which is placed in my Model) in my Controller? I only get "Call to undefined function guests_age()" when I do $guests_age = guests_age();

Comment: create an object for your model like 
$this->testMode = new Modelclass();
$this->testMode->Modelfunction();

Answer (score 0):

```
public function guests_age($args = array())
{
    $columns = array('location_id', 'created_at', 'gender');
    $query = Guest::select('age');

    foreach($columns as $column)
    {
        if(!empty($args[$column]))
            $query = $query->where($column, $args[$column]);
    }

    return $query->get();        
}

//usage:
guests_age(array('location_id' => '1'));
guests_age(array('location_id' => '1', 'gender' => 'm'));
//etc..
```

Comment: Super compact and clever! Thank you! I'll keep this in my code notebook. Thanks for your quick reply.